# Can I ping a host that has disabled the ICMP Ping option?

Tags: networking, ping, tcp, icmp

I need to know if it's possible to compare and test how fast is an IP (ie: any web or game server) relative to my location (in terms of network latency), even if they have disabled ICMP/Ping requests from their firewall ?

Comment: The firewall will actively refuse the attempt to ping so you'll get inaccurate results as the response time will take into consideration the network hardware and even the network hardware may experience problems and congestion at times so your results will not be accurate...

Comment: @OP: What do you precisely mean by 'fast'. Throughput or latency? I guess latency. Can you please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/843582/edit) your post to clarify that?

Comment: Do I understand correctly the following? - You want to measure the ping [round trip time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-trip_delay_time). By "IP" you mean communication over IP. "They" is your Internet services provider (ISP).

Comment: @Hennes and pabouk: I have updated my post. I just need for instance to compare two or three servers and see which of them has the fastest ping relative to my location, even if they both don't answer ping commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can with hping3 for example by sending a SYN Package to the host:

```
hping3 -S -V host
```

If it is a Webserver you know that port 80 would be open and can send SYN packets to that port

```
hping3 -S -V -p 80 host
```

Or scan the host for any open ports to which you could send packets and he will reply.